may restrict access to the server of postgresql running on the client's computer for the user of windows administrator?
I've recently started coding software and I'm coding a desktop application that uses the PostgreSQL database. The database will work locally on the client's computer. Can I make sure that no user changes the authentication settings of this database? If an administrator user on windows can change the authentication settings via the pg_hba.conf file, They can connect and change the database settings as desired. I heard on the Mssql server that in this case the server authentication setting can be blocked. Instead of logging in as a Windows user, a connection can be created and encrypted by creating a server user. Can I get a system like this using postgresql? Is there anything to do in this case, can you suggest different alternatives?
I did some research and found nothing to work for me. I searched for different libraries based on postgresql, but I couldn't find anything clearly.

No, impossible: The sysadmin can always overrule your authentication.

Does a file-based and password-protected database work for me? Is there a database system you can suggest in that case?

Yeah I think so, you needed an embedded database, something like SQLite
